# Confusing network layout that works

Tags: networking, router

I have a network like this:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/3tamgepdt/]

Blue means Virtual Box virtual machine, yellow means router and white means normal computer.

When I want to communicate with Client using Windows PC I set Firewall as Win PC's gateway so when I run tracert 8.8.8.8 this is the output:

[image: http://s32.postimg.org/i5nj77nnp/tracert.png]

Everything works fine.

What I don't understand is how the packets don't get stuck going back and forth between Win PC and Firewall, because Win PC's gateway is Firewall and Firewall's gateway is Win PC. So my question is, why does this work?

Comment: Please provide both the firewall VM’s and Windows’ routing table.

Comment: I love the diagram, did you draw it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that firewall's default gateway is 192.168.1.113?

The trace you attached suggests that firewall's default gateway is 192.168.1.1.

Because the firewall's eth0 is configured as Vbox Bridged, the firewall can communicate with the TP-link router directly with TCP/IP protocol, with the Windows PC acting as a bridge/switch.